# MYSQL subquery count slow

Tags: mysql

I have the following query that pulls out the information I need, but is too slow to use. It is basically a select query on two tables pulling in various columns and it also includes a count from another table. I would appreciate some help on this, as have been struggling for a couple of days now. I have an index on the tblDriver status column.

```
SELECT date_format(`tblAvailability`.`adate`,'%e %b %Y') AS `adate`,
  date_format(`tblAvailability`.`adate`,'%a') AS `aday`, `tblVenue`.`name` AS `name`, 
  tblAvailability.cars, `tblAvailability`.`adate` AS `bdate`,
`tblAvailability`.`totalslots` AS `totslots`,
(SELECT count(*) FROM `tblDriver` WHERE ((`tblDriver`.`status` <> 'refunded') and (`tblDriver`.`status` <> 'rejected') and (`tblDriver`.`status` <> 'rebook') and (`tblDriver`.`status` <> 'rebook-cust') and (`tblDriver`.`eventid` = `tblAvailability`.`id`))) AS `bslots` 
    FROM (`tblAvailability` join `tblVenue` on((`tblAvailability`.`idvenue` = `tblVenue`.`id`))) 
    WHERE ((`tblAvailability`.`adate` > now()) 
    AND (`tblAvailability`.`status` <> 'inactive') and (`tblAvailability`.`status` <> 'removed')) 
    GROUP BY `tblAvailability`.`adate`,`tblVenue`.`name` 
    ORDER BY `tblAvailability`.`adate`,`tblVenue`.`name`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your query, cleaned up a bit:

```
SELECT date_format(a.`adate`,'%e %b %Y') AS adate, date_format(a.adate, '%a') AS aday, 
       v.name, a.cars, a.adate AS bdate, a.`totalslots` AS `totslots`,
       (SELECT count(*)
        FROM `tblDriver` d
        WHERE d.status not in ('refunded', 'rejected', 'rebook', 'rebook-cust') and
              d.eventid = a.id
       ) AS bslots 
FROM tblAvailability a join
     tblVenue v
     on a.idvenue = v.id
WHERE a.adate > now() AND
      a.status not in ('inactive', 'removed')
GROUP BY a.adate, v.name
ORDER BY a.adate, v.name;
```

Now that it is sort of readable, it is possible to make suggestions.  The index on `driver(status)` probably isn't helping.  Try these indexes:

```
tblDriver(eventid, status)
tblAvailability(adate, status, idvenue)
tblVenue(id)
```

The last is probably not needed, because `venue.id` is probably declared as a primary key.

Comment: That's great. Thank you. Also thank you for the tidy up example. I will examine that and learn from your suggested formatting/layout. I think I was taught/learnt in a slight messy manner. :)

I did have the third index as you thought, but the other two have helped speed it up.

Now I have realised that it is bringing out just the first session of the day, which I have sorted out the totslots, by adding sum to a.totalslots. Just need to work out how to sum the bslots in the subquery.